# How do I access a file that I uploaded to a folder from a Transform?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I uploaded an image file into a folder in Foundry, and I want to use it as an input to a Transform.  It looks like it's stored as some kind of resource in a service called Blobster, how can I access this file and use it?

Answer (score 1):

When you drag and drop a file into a folder *without making a dataset to hold it first*, this puts the file into a different service (Blobster) than the one that serves the files to your Transform.  As such, you would have to talk to that separate service in order to use its contents in your Transform.

Instead, I'd recommend you upload the file *into a dataset*, by making an empty dataset first, then dragging and dropping the file into the dataset.  Once it's inside the dataset, then you can use it as a standard input to a Transform without any extra work.  You'll simply access the file the same as you would any other file input.